# How can I fix error message given by React Developper Tools on the default React page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, npm

## Summary

I would like to check elements on the react app, but my React Developper Tools on Google Chrome didn't work.

## Proplem

Error message on the browser React Developper

```
This page is using the development build of React. 

Note that the development build is not suitable for production.
Make sure to use the production build before deployment.

Open the developer tools, and "Components" and "Profiler" tabs will appear to the right.
```

## What I tried to do

It was succeeded to build and execute a sample react app.

```
npm init react-app react_app
npm start
```

I can see the default React screen on `http://localhost:3000/` and I didn't edit the created react app folder.

[image]

However, my React Developper didn't work with the red colored warning icon.

Comment: I didn’t think you could create a “CRA” using `npm init`. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, then I tried in incognito window in chrome (ctrl + shift + N) which worked. Also, you can clear the cache or open a new tab and try there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no issue it's jut info thes you are in development mode

If you visit a site with React in development mode, the icon will have a red background:
React DevTools on a website with development version of React
It is expected that you use the development mode when working on your app, and the production mode when deploying your app to the users.

check this URL
[https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build]

Answer (score 0):

run this command

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

**If your project is built with Create React App, run:**

**npm run build**

This will create a production build of your app in the build/ folder of your project.

Remember that this is only necessary before deploying to production. For normal development, use **npm start**.

Answer (score 0):

At first I also thought that I could not use the react developer tools if the red icon was there, but actually it doesn't matter, just click the little arrows at the top to see more tabs.
 [screenshot of my react developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAIHw.png) [A screenshot of my components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTZAt.png)